JPG in anchor tag HREF resizes wrong in Android Chrome
In this HTML snippet, within a basic document served to both a Windows laptop (Firefox or Edge) and a Android mobile (Chrome) browser, the original JPG sizes fine, but when clicked-through the <a> tag, resizes unexpectedly on Android.  For laptop, and {many} JPGs, it resizes to fit the available window size.  For many JPGs on Android, the image gets {really big} overflowing the available window size.
<a href="someimage.jpg">
    <img border="0" src="someimage.jpg">
</a>

Is there an attribute set inside the JPG that governs this correct / incorrect sizing?  (Maybe this gets set irregularly based on the source of the JPG).  Or should I mess with CSS or the document <meta ...> to attempt a correction?
You can see the problem in action here: http:\aquatantravel.com\SamJoyce note that "chapter 1" mostly works, but chapter 9 pictures overflow on an Android.
Thank you for considering this seemingly odd browser behavior.

The issue you are encountering seems to be with how you are styling your image with CSS.
In a web browser on a phone or on a computer/laptop, each browser can interpret image sizing differently, especially when handling higher-resolution images on a mobile device.
It's more than likely that CSS will resolve this behavior as some mobile browsers do no automatically scale larger images to fit the viewport.
Using CSS, you can make sure images adjust to their container size using the max-width property on the image and set it to 100% as well as setting the height property to auto.
Example:
`<a href="someImage.jpg">
  <img border="0" src="someImage.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;">
</a>`

This will insure the image will be 100% of it's container , scaling down as needed on smaller screens (the max-width property). It will also maintain the aspect ratio of the image, which prevents distortion (the height property).
The other possible issue could be how you have your viewport meta tag set up. In the head of your HTML file, having this line of code below, will help the browser scale images and other elements based on the device screen size:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"`

I hope this information has been helpful for you.

Thanks Braeden, I will try this tomorrow and let you know.  To be clear, the  part displays as expected, but the click through from the  element is what is giving me grief.  I appreciate your attention to this question!

Nope, none of these approaches seem to work.  I tried all combinations of the  and style= present and absent, and the style amended to both the  and  elements.  I don't think the click-through from  is recognizing the CSS as the  does (which works as one would expect).
